# PHP if multiple variables exist

Tags: php, html, variables, isset

So i'm having a bit of a problem with having my PHP run a command if multiple variables exist.  I made a simple version for people to see what i'm trying to fix easier.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help :)

```
<?php
if ((isset($finalusername)) && if (isset($finalpassword)) && if (isset($finalemail)))
  echo "This will save.";
?>
```

Comment: you do not have any code posted

Comment: Without code, we can't do anything! I posted a basic answer with a code that I use for this purpose...

Comment: <?php
if ((isset($finalusername)) && if (isset($finalpassword)) && if (isset($finalemail)))
  echo "This will save.";
?>

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (isset($finalusername, $finalpassword, $finalemail))
```

Also see [The Definitive Guide to PHP's `isset` and `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset).

Comment: @alex When something annoys me enough and I have some spare time on my hands. :o)

Comment: I want everyone to know.....im an idiot lol the variable was finalpass and thats why i was having trouble haha, but thanks everyone your codes were way ebtetr than mine :)

Comment: Can empty() also receive multiple parameters such as isset()? I just want to be sure. By the way, I've read the article. It's comprehensive! Nice one!

Comment: @deceze, thanks. I've just tried and NetBeans gave a syntax error, hehehe. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to place the multiple `if` in there.

```
if (isset($finalusername) && isset($finalpassword) && isset($finalemail)) {
   // ...
}
```

In fact, I'd even do it like so...

```
if (isset($finalusername, $finalpassword, $finalemail)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I want everyone to know.....im an idiot lol the variable was finalpass and thats why i was having trouble haha, but thanks everyone your codes were way ebtetr than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only
>   if all of the parameters are set.

So you can do this way:

```
if (isset($finalusername, $finalpassword, $finalemail)) {
    echo "This will save.";
}
```

Comment: I want everyone to know.....im an idiot lol the variable was finalpass and thats why i was having trouble haha, but thanks everyone your codes were way ebtetr than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

So this might be a good solution for much more than some variables:

```
  // INTI ARRAY
  $arr_final = array(
    'username'  => !empty($finalusername) ? $finalusername : false,
    'password'  => !empty($finalpassword) ? $finalpassword : false,
    'email'  => !empty($finalemail) ? $finalemail : false,
    'more_stuff'  => !empty($morestuff) ? $morestuff : false,
  );

  $bol_isValid = true;
  $arr_required = array('username','password');
  foreach ($arr_final as $key => $value) {
    if ( (in_array($key, $arr_required)) && ($value === false) ) {
      $bol_isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try with this:

```
if (isset($var1))
{
    if (isset($var2))
    {
        // continue for each variables...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed this before and Im not sure why but it isn't working...
<php?
if (isset($finalusername))
{
    if (isset($finalpassword))
    {
      echo "please work";  
    }
}
?>